# Unable to get rid of root user and privileges

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, root

I am told that the most basic security to set up in Linux is to change the superuser name from `root` to something obscure

so I run these steps to add new user

```
$ /usr/sbin/adduser new_username
$ passwd new_usersname
```

then went to give ssh access to new user

```
$ /usr/sbin/visudo
root           ALL=(ALL)        ALL  // didn't modify this
new_username   ALL=(ALL)        ALL  //added this
```

Now despite the above change, my new user `new_username` does not have superuser privileges. I am always forced to change to root using `su` use root privileges.

So, what I want is to remove completely the `root` account, and give all root's power to my `new_user`

How do I accomplish this task ?

Comment: Removing the root user is impossible (for a ton of good reasons). That is not what you want to do; you want to give your user permanent root permissions. But, you shouldn't do that either. You should learn how to use `sudo` safely and effectively.

Comment: You write about giving ssh access, but you configure sudo... Did you check, wheather sudo works or not? (https://superuser.com/questions/553932/how-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-access)

Comment: There is already a question about [changing root's name](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/how-do-you-rename-root), but that is a weird thing to do. If you want security it would make more sense to prevent directly login as superuser, and do everything through `sudo`.

Comment: You talk about renaming root, but your information shows you trying to add another sudo user, and your comments talk about using `su` not `sudo`. This all makes no sense. Then as mentioned, removing 'root' is a very bad idea. Where are you getting this info?

Comment: Wow, I never knew changing root user was such an issue. @Tobias Yes. I can use sudo, but only after a password prompt. I am just trying (at-leasst) to deter an attacker from knowing there is a user called root

Comment: @Patrick Well, I came up with it actually. I am trying to stick to the old advice that in the case of a login application, telling a user's email is ok, at-least gives half the information to a potential attacker.

Comment: *"I am told that the most basic security to set up in Linux is to change the superuser name from root to something obscure"* **This is garbage. G A R B A G E.**  Whoever told you that, don't listen to them again.  **It will be drop dead easy to get the new username anyway, it's the user with UID 0.**  And if it ain't uid 0, it's whoever owns all the system files.  And if that ain't the superuser, you have just introduced a big *security hole*, not to mention broken things that may require it.  Forget about this now.

Comment: `Forget about this now` DONE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your new user `new_username` will not have root privileges after editing the `sudoers` file.  This change only allows `new_username` to run `sudo` in order to run a task with superuser privileges:

```
$touch testfile
$chown new_username testfile
chown: changing ownership of 'testfile': Operation not permitted
$sudo chown new_username testfile
[sudo] password for new_username:
$
```

There are various debates about renaming the `root` account.  It would probably be better to make it secure instead of renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always disable a root account by setting his login prompt to `nologin` in `/etc/passwd` file. However, after setting this, you would not be able to use `root` account even using `ssh` or `su`.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

Now, as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user) link, after setting `sudo` privileges to an user, the user must log off and log in back again for the effects to take place.